# Parsing an "array" string JSON with JAVA

Tags: java, json, websocket

I have data coming from a websocket in JSON format.

```
{"Type":112,"F":[1,2,3974.909912109375,27500,1639207185]}
```

Im parsing it like this...

```
obj = new JSONObject(text);
Object o = obj.get("F");
System.out.println(o);
```

Which gives me...

```
[1,2,3974.909912109375,27500,1639207185]
```

In the console.

My question is, is this a string or an object or what is it?
I can't seem to access the indexes.

```
  o.get(0);
```

If I try to cast it to a string, my program crashes???

```
 String s = (String) o;
```

So I have no idea what this is? And how to access the data in it.
Any ideas?? As to what this actually is??  Is it just an Array?? I feel like its simply a string, but its not???

I simply what to read the values....ie

```
 o[0] = 1;   o[3] = 27500
```

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out...

```
obj = new JSONObject(text);
JSONArray jArr = (JSONArray) obj.get("F");
```

Then I can do

```
 jArr.get(0);  etc...
```

Comment: Instead of casting, you can use `obj.getJsonArray("F");`. There's a bunch of other `get` methods for other types as well.

Comment: @QBrute awesome thanks :)